# How to Write to line by line in a single file on different methods in java

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I would like to write in a single file in java but in different methods. I wrote this

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
  public static File file = new File("text.log");


  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {
    FileWriter input= new FileWriter(file);
    input.write("hello");
    input.write("\n");
    input.close();
    test();
   }

  public  static void test() throws IOException
   {

    FileWriter input= new FileWriter(file);
    input.write("world");
    input.write("\n");
    input.close();
   }


}
```

The output is just `world`. It looks like calling the function `test()` overwrites what was previously written.

Comment: Others have mentioned append mode, but why not make the `FileWriter` itself a class variable and open it only once?

Comment: The real lesson here is: study the documentation for the classes you are using! That is the essence of programming: when you start using a new library class, you **first** study it to understand how it works and what it is doing for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `new FileWriter(file, true)`, it will append instead of overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the `FileWriter` in append mode by passing `true` as the second argument:

```
public static File file = new File("text.log", true);
```

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)):

> **public FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)**
>   Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Comment: I assume you mean FileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true); because when I put wja you just mentioned on my code, It says that I can not resolve "java.lang.String, boolean

Comment: @user3841581 The Javadoc clearly mentions a constructor which takes a boolean and string.